# How to crawl an offline web page with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web-crawler, jsoup

I want to crawl through a web page that is stored on the computer using jsoup. The thing is i find all the links on the first page of the site.

example: `Jsoup.parse(C:/Users/MuhammadNaeem/Downloads/Compressed/IRWS_Main_Assignment/literature.offline/authors/carroll-lewis/index.html,"UTF-8");`

```
for(Element x: doc.getElementsByTag("a")){
                System.out.println("OUTLINK -> "+x.attr("href"));
        }
```

First problem I only need the links that are only stored offline.

But the problem that i am facing is that the href of the links that are offline are incomplete and i cant continue on crawling.
This is one of the href i get.

```
alices-adventures-in-wonderland/index.html
```

Is there any way i can auto direct and parse these offline links. I dont know i am confused.

Because for parsing through Jsoup i need a file for offline page. and the path i get from the first page or incomplete for further crawling.

My WebCrawler Class Code is below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class MyCrawler {
    String s;

    public static Document doc =null;
    public static File input=null;
    static String u="C:/Users/MuhammadNaeem/Downloads/Compressed/IRWS_Main_Assignment/literature.offline/authors/carroll-lewis/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        check(u,true);  
        }

    public static void check(String url,boolean c){
        try {
            if(c==true){
                File input=new File(u+"index.html");
                doc = Jsoup.parse(input,"UTF-8");
            }
            else{
                File input=new File(u+url);
                doc = Jsoup.parse(input,"UTF-8");
                //System.out.println(doc);
            }
            for(Element x: doc.getElementsByTag("a")){
                try{
                    Jsoup.connect(x.attr("href"));
                    System.out.println("OUTLINK -> "+x.attr("href"));
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    if(x.attr("href").equals("index.html")==true || x.attr("href").equals("index-2.html")==true || x.attr("href").contains("../") ==true ){
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Offline Link -> "+x.attr("href"));
                        check(x.attr("href"),false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an idea: you could fire up an embedded Java based Webserver that makes those files available on http://localhost:someport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three keypoints that will help you solve your problem:

#### 1) Resolving a relative url into an absolute url

You can take advantage of Jsoup ability to resolve an relative url into an absolute url. However, you need to specify explicitly the base URI.

So when you parse an offline page, do it like this:

```
File input = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "file:///" + input.getAbsolutePath());
// Note the file protocol used for base URI----^
```

---

#### 2) Checking that a link is offline

We will use the JDK [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class for checking if a given link is offline or not.

When you find links inside the parsed page, here is how to check that they are offline or not:

```
for (Element x : doc.getElementsByTag("a")) {
    URI uri = URI.create(x.absUrl("href"));
    boolean isOffline = uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("file");

    if (isOffline) {
        System.out.println("Offline Link -> " + x.attr("href"));
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

#### 3) Turning an offline link into an absolute filepath

Here we will use the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. Check the sample code below:

```
URI uri = ...
String absolutePath = new File(uri.getPath()).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see an href without a beginning path, it is relative to your current path.

So you are at

`C:/Users/MuhammadNaeem/Downloads/Compressed/IRWS_Main_Assignment/literature.offline/authors/carroll-lewis/index.html`

which has a base path of

`C:/Users/MuhammadNaeem/Downloads/Compressed/IRWS_Main_Assignment/literature.offline/authors/carroll-lewis/`

And you see

```
alices-adventures-in-wonderland/index.html
```

Means you'd go to your base path plus that link, which is

`C:/Users/MuhammadNaeem/Downloads/Compressed/IRWS_Main_Assignment/literature.offline/authors/carroll-lewis/alices-adventures-in-wonderland/index.html`

Comment: If i am doing it recursively, i cant seem to figure out a way to add each hrefs, because i don't know how i can remove the index.html each time and put the new href. I hope it make sense.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Why can't you remove the filename from the path? Just take the substring of the current path up to the last slash.

Comment: If i remove the filename from the path. Then i wont be able to use the Jsoup.parse(File,String);. And Jsoup.connect is not working on just the path till the last slash.

Comment: I'm saying when you need to follow a new link. If it is a relative path, take the current path without the filename, add the new path, then parse the new file.